# use nodejs connect stmp server failed?

Tags: node.js, networking, smtp

I use Node.js' 'nodemailer' and 'tls' packages to send e-mail，but the response is:

```
451 Authentication failed: Could not authenticate
```

use 'TLSv1.2' auth by user and pass，I don't know why?
I can telent SMTP host and port

```js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const tls = require('tls');
```

```js
// 创建可重用的邮件传输器对象
let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'xxx',
    port: 456,
    secure: true, 
    auth: {
        user: 'xxx',
        pass: 'xxx'
    }
    ,
    tls: {
        minVersion: 'TLSv1.2'
    }
});

// 配置邮件选项
let mailOptions = {
    from: 'xxx',
    to: 'xxx',
    subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
    text: 'Hello World!'
};
console.log(1)
// 使用邮件传输器对象发送邮件
transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } else {
        console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
    }
});
```

I tried using 'TLSv1.1' and 1.2 and Java, Python and Node.js，none worked. I think the password is wrong，but my client says its correct. They gave us this password.
[image: image of the error]